# How do I populate a dropdown list with the past 30 days of dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, out-of-memory

I am trying to populate a Dropdown list with the past 30 dates and I am receiving the error:

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

This is my function to fill the Drop Down List:

```
public void FillDates(int NumDaysBack)
{
    for (DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-NumDaysBack); d < DateTime.Now; d.AddDays(1))
    {
        ddMiscDateList.Items.Add(d.ToShortDateString());
    }
    ddMiscDateList.Items.Add("Other");
}
```

I am calling this function on load and using 30 for NumDaysBack.  How can I write this more efficiently to not receive this error?

Comment: Instead of using `DateTime.Now` you might want to switch to `DateTime.Today`, it removes the time portion of the date. It is the same as doing `DateTime.Now.Date`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DateTime.AddDays()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns new instance of DateTime. It doesn't change d variable. Because of it you have infinite loop.
You can fix it

```
public void FillDates(int NumDaysBack)
{
    for (DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-NumDaysBack); d < DateTime.Now; d = d.AddDays(1))
    {
        ddMiscDateList.Items.Add(d.ToShortDateString());
    }
    ddMiscDateList.Items.Add("Other");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void FillDates(int NumDaysBack)
{
    for (DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-NumDaysBack); d < DateTime.Now; d = d.AddDays(1))
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^-fixed here
    {
        ddMiscDateList.Items.Add(d.ToShortDateString());
    }
    ddMiscDateList.Items.Add("Other");
}
```

When you call d.AddDays(1) it returns new instance of DateTime (without updating d)

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `d.AddDays(1)` you are getting a new instance of `DateTime` i.e. you are not applying any changes to your `DateTime d` object. Therefore your loop never terminates and you end up running out of memory.

The solution is to write `d = d.AddDays(1)` instead.

From the MSDN documentation:

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.

Also, if you're only interested in arithmetic (in your case addition) on actual days, then you may want to omit the actual time part and instead use:

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

or simplified:

```
DateTime.Today
```

You will still have the time part but it will be set to 00:00:00

DateTime Today Property:

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.
>
> Because it returns the current date without the current time, the Today property is suitable for use in applications that work with dates only.

Conversely if you only want to use the time of the day use `DateTime.TimeOfDay` which returns a `DateTime` object without the current day.

Answer (score 0):

When generating sequences sometimes Enumerable.Range can be a good alternative.
Something like.

```
    public void FillDates(int NumDaysBack)
    {
        ddMiscDateList.Items = Enumerable.Range(0, NumDaysBack).Select(x => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-NumDaysBack + x));
    }
```

Comment: I tried this since it looks faster, however, it just gave me an error message.  The loop is working fine for me though.

Comment: It's not faster. It does the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps a .ToList () at the end solves the error. I should have added that.